# AndEngine update cycle and black screen issues

Tags: android, andengine

I'm writing a little layer on andEngine to make it a bit more user friendly, but I'm finding some problems. Could anybody be so kind helping here?

1) I have something called "Screen" that encapsulates a scene splitting its logic, etc... The problem is when I want to move from a Screen to another. I would like to know when a frame ends/start to do the swapping, because there will be a lot of problems if I do this between a frame.

2) When my phone sleeps I'm getting a black screen when returning to the game. I guess this is because textures being invalidated, how can I make them to be reloaded? I have tried a direct call to Engine->Texture Manager->onReload() without luck.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### QUESTION 1 : HANDLING SCENE TRANSITIONS

With regards to question #1, it may be helpful for you to take a look at this tutorial:

http://stuartmct.co.uk/2012/07/16/andengine-scenes-and-scene-management/

The basic solution advocated there (which I think works nicely) is to create something in the vein of a SceneManager class which, as StuartMcT describes, handles

- Defining the scene types
- Loading the resources required by the scenes
- Creating the scenes
- Setting the currently displayed scene
- etc.

You mentioned that you'd like to know when a "frame" ends/starts--I assume you mean scene transition?  His approach offers a onCreateSceneFinished() method, which you could use to do anything that must wait until that time.

### QUESTION 2 : HANDLING PAUSE/RESUME

The starting point for addressing this is going to be adding logic to the onPause() and onResume() methods in the activity.  How you handle these will depend on your game, but consider throwing an mEngine.start() in the onResume() method and an mEngine.pause() in the pause() and see how that affects things.

If you post some code, may be able to assist further.

Comment: No problem, I addressed the issue by myself, but your post is really helpfull too.